# How to communicate to an HTTPS service from mobile device using Codename one?

Tags: codenameone

How to communicate to an HTTPS service from mobile device? Generally on the client side we do have to provide a key store path from where it will pick up the public key used for encryption, and then send the call to the HTTPS enabled server.

-How can we achieve the above process in code name one client ?

-How to publish such certificate public key to app store in apk?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ConnectionRequest class to do all https request and response services.

**For example:-**

```
ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest() {
            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
               }
                       };
                       req1.setPost(false);
                       req1.setUrl("http://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me");
                       req1.addArgumentNoEncoding("fields", "feed{name,full_picture,message,story}");
                       req1.addArgumentNoEncoding("access_token", token);
                       NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(req1);
```

You can set http url by using .setUrl() method. And the response is store in input parameter passed in ConnectionRequest().